# Read remote mp3 file information using php

Tags: php, mp3, id3lib, getid3

I am working on a site which will fetch mp3 details from a remote url.  I need to write a cron job so that it gets all the song information such as the file name, path, artist, genre, bitrate, playing time, etc and put it in a database table.

I tried getid3 package, but this is very slow when fetching more than one url at a time and I get maximum execution error.

Example:

```
require_once('getid/getid3/getid3.php');

    $urls = array ('http://stackoverflow.com/test1.mp3','http://stackoverflow.com/test2.mp3''http://stackoverflow.com/test3.mp3');


    foreach($urls  as $ur){
      $mp3_det = getMp3Info( $ur );
      print_r ($mp3_det);

    }

    function getMp3Info ( $url ){
            if($url){
            /**********/
            $filename = tempnam('/tmp','getid3');
            if (file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($url, false, null, 0, 35000))) {
               if (require_once('getid/getid3/getid3.php')) {
                  $getID3 = new getID3;
                  $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($filename);
                  unlink($filename);
                  $bitratez = $ThisFileInfo[audio][bitrate] ? $ThisFileInfo[audio][bitrate] : '';
                  $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
                  if ((!array_key_exists("Content-Length", $headers))) { return false; }
                 // print $headers["Content-Length"];
                  $filesize= round($headers["Content-Length"]/1000);
                  $contentLengthKBITS=$filesize*8;
                  if ( $bitratez ){
                         $bitrate= round ( $bitratez/1000 );
                        $seconds=$contentLengthKBITS/$bitrate;
                        $playtime_mins = floor($seconds/60);
                        $playtime_secs = $seconds % 60;

                         if(strlen($playtime_secs)=='1'){$zero='0';}
                        $playtime_secs = $zero.$playtime_secs;
                        $playtime_string=$playtime_mins.':'.$playtime_secs;
                    }
                    else $playtime_string='0:00';

                 // echo '<pre>'.print_r($ThisFileInfo, true).'</pre>';
               }

               $bitrate = $bitrate ? $bitrate : 0;

                $ret = array();
                $ret['playtime'] = $playtime_string;
                $ret['filesize'] = $filesize;
                $ret['bitrate']  = $bitrate;

               return $ret;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? I assume  you already know about the `max_execution_time` parameter? I think changing that, or splitting the whole thing into multiple jobs, are the only ways to go

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to help the execution time by using a socket connection and reading in chunks of the file at a time, and continuously trying to analyze the file.

Since ID3 data is stored in the beginning of the mp3, there is no point in downloading the entire thing.  THe biggest problem I see right now is that the analyze function only takes a filename, not binary data (which is what you would have).  So, you would have to either update the code, or make a similar function to analyze that works with your binary data.

Answer (score 0):

MP3 files comes along with some kind of Meta Data almost same way to some other binary file formats. They are in ID tags. There are many versions of ID tags, like ID3 or ID4 tags. Now, there is easy way to extract IDv3 tag informations supplied along with MP3 file, through PHP.

You need to download some library in PHP from sourceforge, like getID3. This way you can extract artist name, genre, duration, length, size etc information from an mp3 file. IDv4 contains additional informations such as album art.